# using Expression to extract the full qualified name of a property include the namespace

Tags: lambda, .net-4.5

I have this property (it is a resource key):

```
A.B.C.D
<Namespace>.<Namespace>.<Class>.<Property>
```

using various Expression samples found from googling, they only produce result "D".

However, I want the full path including the namespace,

so I can dynamically create the resourceManager using the baseName (derived as till before the property name) and key (property) to retrieve a resource.

```
string fullQN = ExpressionMagic.DeriveFullQN(A.B.C.D.); // <- possible?
var dot = fullQN.LastIndexOf('.');
var key = fullQN.Substring(dot + 1);
var baseName = fullQN.Substring(0, dot);
var rsxMgr = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(baseName, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string resx = rsxMgr.GetString(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

string DeriveFQN<T>(Expression<Func<T>> p)
    {
        var mbr = ((MemberExpression)p.Body).Member;
        var fqn = string.Format("{0}.{1}", mbr.DeclaringType.FullName, mbr.Name);

        return fqn;
    }
```